# Hide p:dataTable selection checkbox based on row criteria

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, selection

I have implemented `org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel`.

Now when rendering my `<p:dataTable>` based on the `SelectableDataModel` I add a column with checkboxes by using:

```
<p:column selectionMode="multiple" />
```

For some rows I do not want the checkbox to appear, based on some attribute of the row.

I cannot see a way to do this.  Is it possible with out the box Prime Faces functionality ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable the checkbox:

```
<p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:18px" 
   disabledSelection="#{car.color =='Black'}" 
   styleClass="#{car.color =='Black' ? 'selectionDisabled':''}"/>
```

The check box is now disabled, however, visible. Hide disabled checkbox with CSS:

```
td.selectionDisabled .ui-chkbox{
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest to use:

```
<p:dataTable disabledSelection="#{car.color =='Black'}" ... >
```

For me it works fine with PF 5.1. No need to manipulate column styleClass.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm placing the disabledSelection attribute on the dataTable works for primefaces 6.1 as per user4165984.

```
<p:dataTable disabledSelection="#{car.color =='Black'}" ... >
```

or

```
<p:dataTable disabledSelection="#{car.disabled}" ... >
```

Setting the style class is only required if you want to add some fancy css magic to do more than just disable.

Answer (score -1):

As of Primefaces 5.2, the disabledSelection attribute of p:column suggested by maciek and planetjones does **not** disable the checkbox.

disabledSelection attribute should be plugged into the p:datatable tag as suggested by user4165984 or as mentioned [here](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=38042).

Comment: Please be more clear while answering... it helps the OP to figure out what you are trying to suggest. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Please explain what is not clear on my answer. I asked users to go straight with <p:dataTable disabledselection="#{car.color=='Black'}"../> as suggested by user4165984, instead of the most upvoted/accepted answer above it.

Comment: Then comment and upvote the other answer. No need to create an additional  one.